# How to loop through JSON array until condition is met?

Tags: javascript

just started learning JavaScript and trying to figure out the right way to iterate through an array to simulate a login process.

```js
function validateLogin() {
  var userdata = {
    "users": [{
      "username": "james",
      "password": "pass1"
    }, {
      "username": "russel",
      "password": "pass2"
    }, {
      "username": "jane",
      "password": "pass3"
    }, {
      "username": "jeff",
      "password": "pass4"
    }]
  };
  var uname = document.getElementById("username");
  var pword = document.getElementById("password");

  var user = userdata.users;

  for (var item in user) {
    if (user[item].username == uname && user[item].password == pword) {
      alert("Correct Username and Password")
    } else {
      alert("Incorrect Username or Password");
    }
  }
}
```

Problem is its storing all the data "user[item].username" when its meant to store one part of the array say [0] then check if "uname" and "pword" is the same if not carry on until it is and if not the authentication details are incorrect.

I'm sure am meant to do something like count = user[item].username; then count++ to the next iteration?

Either way I'm not getting it! can anyone help pls?

Comment: that's not json. That's plain old javascript. json is a text-encoded version of  JS data structure for transport/transmittion. You have a regular JS data structure definition there.

Comment: Depending on what result you want, the `some`, `every`, `find` and `findIndex` methods do that.

Comment: FYI, you're comparing a string to a DOM element. You probably wanted the `.value` of each of the elements, assuming they're `input`s. If you want to stop the loop when a match is found, you can use a `break` statement. And `for-in` isn't a great choice for Arrays in JS.

Comment: Might loop over using userdata.users.forEach( ... ) instead.  Also, lodash makes operations like these trivial.  userdata.users is a collection (array of objects), and thus you could _.find(userdata.users, {'username': 'james', 'password': 'pass1'}) and if response is undefined, the user can't log in.

Comment: @marcB is it? damn what have i been learning all this time?
what is the correct way of doing it  to reflect JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop is just fine; I suspect the true problem with your code, as @squint mentioned, is that you are comparing strings to DOM elements rather than to the values (presumably) contained within those elements.

However, there are a couple of ways you could improve that loop of yours. First, you mention you do not want the loop to continue on if it has found what it is looking for. You can accomplish this with the [`break` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break):

```
  for (var item in users) {
    if (users[item].username == uname && users[item].password == pword) {
      break;
    }
  }
```

Of course, that just gets you out of the loop, but doesn't record any information about HOW you got out of the loop. For that, you can consider initializing a variable to hold your `user` object, and referencing it outside the loop (note that here, I have saved `userdata.users` in a variable called `users` rather than `user`, since that sounds better and allows us to use `user` to store the actual individual user we're looking for):

```
  var users = userdata.users;
  var user;

  for (var item in users) {
    if (users[item].username == uname && users[item].password == pword) {
      user = users[item];
      break;
    }
  }

  if (user) {
    console.log("Welcome " + user.username);
  } else {
    console.log("Invalid username or password");
  }
```

Note also that the JavaScript [`for .. in` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) in in many ways not the ideal way to iterate over Arrays. It would be better to use the brand-new [`for .. of` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) if you can, and a good ol' `for` loop if not:

```
  var users = userdata.users;
  var user;

  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (users[i].username == uname && users[i].password == pword) {
      user = users[i];
      break;
    }
  }

  if (user) {
    console.log("Welcome " + user.username);
  } else {
    console.log("Invalid username or password");
  }
```

Finally, if you want to get really fancy and you are using ES6, the very latest stable version of JavaScript, you can use the brand-new [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method:

```
var user = userdata.users.find(function (user) {
  return user.username === uname && user.password === pword;
});
```

```js
function validateLogin() {
  var userdata = {
    "users": [
      {"username": "james", "password": "pass1"},
      {"username": "russel", "password": "pass2"},
      {"username": "jane", "password": "pass3"},
      {"username": "jeff", "password": "pass4"}
    ]
  };

  var uname = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var pword = document.getElementById("password").value;

  var users = userdata.users;
  var user;

  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (users[i].username == uname && users[i].password == pword) {
      user = users[i];
      break;
    }
  }

  if (user) {
    console.log("Welcome " + user.username);
  } else {
    console.log("Invalid username or password");
  }

  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onSubmit="validateLogin()">
  <input type="text" id="username" />
  <input type="password" id="password" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: This was very helpful and educational, appreciations!

Answer (score 0):

Hey ran across this question while searching for an `until` loop example in javascript... no luck there but I've tested a `while` loop option on [jsconsole](https://jsconsole.com) that you may like

### TLDR/One-Liner

```
var arr = ['first']; arr.push('second', 'third'); var i = 0; while (i < arr.length){ console.log(arr[i]); i++; };
```

### Scriptlet version

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
// Assign first word/line/character into array type variable
var arr = ['first'];
// Push further values into array setup above
arr.push('second', 'third');
// Assign index for array to start point
var i = 0;
// Start while loop and continue while index value is less then array total length
while (i < arr.length){
    // Present currently processed array indexed value
    console.log(arr[i]);
    // Place more processing lines here
    // Add one to index variable for array before allowing loop to exit or parse the next index
    i++;
};
// close while loop
```

In either of the above the output *should* be the same... looks like there's already plenty of examples for `if` checks so pick the one ya like to throw in to above for testing around with.

Answer (score -2):

You use the wrong loop

```
var usr;
for(var i=0; i<userdata.users.length; i++){
    usr = userdata.users[i];
    // do your stuff with usr
}
```

or:

```
userdata.users.forEach(function(usr, index, allUsers){
    // do your stuff with usr
});
```